# Assigning a Value from an MS Access Table to a Variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm attempting something that I believe should be very simple but it does not work.  I've got a repeater macro in MS Access that I want to use to output a set of data to a series of files.  I'm pulling the current record from my Table CurrentSt, field StCurr.  There is only 1 record in this table

In order to include StCurr in the name of the output, I'm doing the following:

```
 Dim VarOutPut As String
 VarOutPut = CurrentSt.StCurr
```

I'm then calling VarOutPut in my export command.  This works when I set VarOutPut to a fixed number (e.g. VarOutPut = "1000") but when I try to call the value from the CurrentSt table I get an "Object Required" error.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably dozens of options for what you're asking. Without knowing more about the structure of your data, this is one possibility:

```
VarOutPut = DLookup("StCurr", "CurrentSt")
```

This assumes there is only one value / row in your table.

Otherwise, you will need another method.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentSt has to have a reference to a specific table.   you can lookup values using the DLookup function

```
varoutput=DLookup("StCurr","CurrentSt",[Any criteria]) as [Type]
```

it would really be helpful to see all of your code.